# Why is "-8+etch15" appended to this customer's PHP version string?

Tags: php, version, debian

I had a customer report a wierd behavior related to `PHP-#38146`

I did `var_dump(phpversion())` and I get:

```
string(14) "5.2.0-8+etch15"
```

What the heck is the -8, and the +etch15, some sort of Debian related extension of PHP? Related to hardened PHP or something? Does this mean they are essentially running a 5.2.0 build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This section of Debian's documentation might answer some of your questions : [5.6.12 Version](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) *(quoting*) :

> The version number of a package. The
>   format is:
>   `[epoch:]upstream_version[-debian_revision]`

And *(there is more on that page, only quoting parts of it)* :

> **upstream_version** 
> This is the main part of the version number. It is
>   usually the version number of the
>   original ("upstream") package from
>   which the .deb file has been made, if
>   this is applicable. Usually this will
>   be in the same format as that
>   specified by the upstream author(s);
>
> **debian_revision** 
> This part of the version number specifies the
>   version of the Debian package based on
>   the upstream version. It may contain
>   only alphanumerics and the characters
>   + . ~ (plus, full stop, tilde)

In your case, with "5.2.0-8+etch15" :

- "`5.2.0`" is the upstream_version
- and "`8+etch15`" is the debian_revision

Which means, as you guessed, that you are running PHP 5.2.0.

Comment: Note also that Ubuntu, being a Debian derivative, does the same thing, although a bit less cryptically. It reports something like `5.2.6.3ubuntu4.2`.

Comment: More specifically, "8+etch15" means that the underlying package is a security update to Debian 4.0 (codename 'etch'). Traditionally, debian_revision is a plain number, starting with "-1" for the first package of a new upstream version. It's a convention to append '+codenameN' for security fixes. Therefore 5.2.0-8+etch15 is the fiftheenth security fix of the php5 5.2.0 package released with Debian 4.0 ('etch'), which was php5 5.2.0-8. For the whole story: http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/p/php5/php5_5.2.0+dfsg-8+etch15/changelog

Answer (score -2):

```
ARG_ENABLE('pgi', 'Generate PGO instrumented binaries', 'no');
+ARG_WITH('pgo', 'Compile optimized binaries using training data from folder', 'no');
+if (PHP_PGI == "yes" || PHP_PGO != "no") {
+   PGOMGR = PATH_PROG('pgomgr', WshShell.Environment("Process").Item("PATH"));
+   if (!PGOMGR) {
+       ERROR("--enable-pgi and --with-pgo options can only be used if PGO capable compiler is present.");
+   }
+   if (PHP_PGI == "yes" && PHP_PGO != "no") {
+       ERROR("Use of both --enable-pgi and --with-pgo not allowed.");
```

Comment: Please also comment the code to be more self-educative.

Comment: No idea what this code implies, but it doesn't seem to answer the question (which is half a decade old!)